# Images uploading, never being requested once finished

Tags: image, upload, ckeditor

In short, using CKEditor with the Upload Image plugin (http://ckeditor.com/addon/uploadimage). The URL is configured properly (`/services/api/ticket/3/upload`), and when an image is dragged and dropped, the file is uploaded. My server handles the upload, and then sends the response:

`{uploaded:1,fileName:"steve.jpg",url:"/attachment/20.aspx"}`

Which matches what's required on the documentation (http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_file_upload).

So, at the completion of the upload, a green messagebar shows, saying 'File uploaded successfully!', but the image is a small black square - there's no subsequent request for the URL image. Now, as I was working on the server side, a few times I WAS able to get CKEditor to then re-request the given URL and display the image, but when I got the final server-side code into place, it stopped that, and I'm not sure what I would have changed to stop CKEditor from re-requesting the file.

So I was wondering if maybe a response header is incorrect, or am missing something in the return data. I can post response/request headers if needed.

Thanks in advance ya'll..
--Mike

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, tracked it down.

Apparently the 'LoopIndex Track Changes' addon, when enabled, prevents CKEditor from re-loading the image and displaying properly.

(Would have just deleted the question, but then realized that someone else may run into this, so..)